# `Warning: React does not recognize the `rowDirection` prop on a DOM element.` but I don't find any code with `rowDirection`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my demo,
https://codesandbox.io/s/4uhlh3

there report issue with:

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `rowDirection` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `rowdirection` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at div
    at s2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_theme-file-explorer.js?v=a0eb14be:826:22)
    at DragDropContainer2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:4969:7)
    at div
    at c2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_theme-file-explorer.js?v=a0eb14be:945:22)
    at DragDropContainer2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:4969:7)
    at div
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:8472:14
    at div
    at ue (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:8520:14)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:8504:17
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:8538:11
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:7459:38
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:10101:28
    at ScrollingComponent (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:5727:34)
    at div
    at ReactSortableTree (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:9985:5)
    at SortableTreeWithoutDndContext
    at DndProvider2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:3681:23)
    at SortableTree (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@nosferatu500_react-sortable-tree.js?v=a0eb14be:10487:22)
    at div
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/src/App.tsx?t=1681521758202:23:43)
```

but I don't find any code with `rowDirection`

[image]

and the `http://localhost:3000/src/App.tsx?t=1681521758202:23:43` refer to:
this line code:

```
const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('css');
```

there is nothing wrong with the code, why it log error there?
BTW, will it affect the running of the program?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, we could find that the source of the `warning` is from the `@nosferatu500/theme-file-explorer` module. The implementation [here](https://github.com/nosferatu500/theme-file-explorer/blob/218cd7b980e945f807c038c61cdf756db87d8808/tree-node-renderer.js#L26) may cause this kind of issue. It just puts the `otherProps` to the `div`. If you are the author or know the author of the repo, you could ask them to take the `rowDirection` out of the `otherProps`.

This module looks like an extension of ReactSortableTree. You may also fix it by changing to other extensions.